# Primefaces - Floating Label in p:panelGrid

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How is one supposed to embed a 'Floating Label' - as described [here](https://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputText.xhtml?jfwid=e4c5c) - into a p:panelGrid?

The problem i have is that 'p:outputLabel' is not shown inside of 'p:inputText' but besides it.

The current code:

```html
<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid id="login-grid" columns="3">
        <span class="ui-float-label">
            <p:inputText id="float-input-username-signin" value=""/>
            <p:outputLabel for="@previous" value="Username"/>
        </span>
        <p:message id="login-username-msg" for="float-input-username-signin"/>
                                
                            
        <span class="ui-float-label">
            <p:password id="float-input-password-signin"/>
            <p:outputLabel for="@previous" value="Password"/>
        </span>
        <p:message id="login-password-msg" for="float-input-password-signin"/>
                            
        <p:commandButton value="Login" id="login-button" update="login-grid" action="#{loginBean.check}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I already tried to put the 'Floating Label' inside of a div container, but it didn't work.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p:panelGrid` (and `h:panelGrid`) should only contain JSF components as direct children. It will render a cell for each of them. So, instead of a `span` tag, use a `h:panelGroup` component (which will render a `span`). And use `columns="2"` instead of 3:

```html
<p:panelGrid id="login-grid" columns="2">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-float-label">
        <p:inputText id="float-input-username-signin" value=""/>
        <p:outputLabel for="@previous" value="Username"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <p:message id="login-username-msg" for="float-input-username-signin"/>

    <h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-float-label">
        <p:password id="float-input-password-signin"/>
        <p:outputLabel for="@previous" value="Password"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <p:message id="login-password-msg" for="float-input-password-signin"/>

    <p:commandButton value="Login" id="login-button" update="login-grid" action="#{loginBean.check}"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```